# changes of integration limits

Tags: analysis

In my studies of mathematics I have encountered the following equality: $$\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{1}{(1+x)^3}dx = \int_{2}^{1} \dfrac{1}{x^3}dx $$

What is a mathematical explanation that would explain that equality?

Comment: Change of variables: let $y=1+x$ (in the original integral), but then also $y$ is a dummy variable (in the new integral) and could be renamed to $x$ again.

Answer (score 1):

It is a change of variable. If you call $u=1+x$ you have the equality
$$\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{1}{(1+x)^3}dx = \int_{1}^{2} \dfrac{1}{u^3}du $$
where the upper limit is $u=x+1=2$ and the lower one $u=1$. Note also that $du=dx$. In your notes, as $u$ is a dummy variable, it is renamed as $x$

Comment: so the upper limit is 2 and the lower one is 1 not the opposite? (or would it change anything nyway)?

Comment: @aribaldi it should as explained in the text (I have corrected the expression). Have you checked that you didn't missed any minus sign in your final expression?

Answer (score 1):

Look at 
$$
\int_a^b f(x) ~dx
$$

Suppose that $F$ is a function with $F'(x) = f(x)$ for every $x$. (One of the parts of the Fundamental theorem of calculus guarantees that there is such a function $F$, although you may not be able to write it down easily.)

Then
$$
\int_a^b f(x) ~dx = F(b) - F(a)
$$
by another part of the FTC.

Now consider the functions 
$$
h(x) = x+1,\\
g(x) = f(h(x)) = f(x+1) \\
G(x)  = F(x+1) = F(h(x))
$$
What's the derivative of $G$? By the chain rule, it's
$$
G'(x) = F'(h(x)) \cdot h'(x) \\
= F'(x+1) \cdot 1 \\
= f(x+1)  \\
= g(x)
$$
So $G$ is an antiderivative of $g$.

Now consider the integral
$$
\int_{a-1}^{b-1} g(x)~dx = \int_{a-1}^{b-1} f(x+1)~dx
$$
By that same FTC, we know that the value of this integral must be
$$
G(a-1)- G(b-1) = F(a) - F(b)
$$
So the two integrals produce the same result.

Your case is a particular application of this analysis, with $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^3}, a = 1, b = 2$.